# How to run ansible tasks serialized

Tags: shell, dictionary, ansible, with-statement

I'm in an odd situation I can't wrap my head around.

I got a collection of fruit, with some attributes,
and at the same time, I am registering a variable, and I try to print both of them in my second task.

My problem would be solved, if I run task 1 and 2 serialized for each fruit, but alas! the first task is collecting all fruits as a list of objects before continuing to task 2.

```
vars:
  fruit:
     - name: banana
       color: yellow

     - name: apple
       color: green

     - name: tomato:
       color: red

tasks:
  - name: Task 1 - Get my hostname
    shell: "hostname -f"
    register: variable

  - name: Task 2 - print my hostname and the fruit

    debug: 
      msg: "hostname.stdout has value {{ variable.stdout }}, the fruits got is: {{ fruit.name }}"
```

Now, I'm not sure what "with_"-loop I should choose for the above situation.

fruit is a dictionary, key+value pair.
"variable.stdout" not sure which object type this is, as we got 3 fruit objects, the .stdout now contains 3 results of the shell command we run here:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "variable": {
        "changed": true, 
        "cmd": "hostname -f", 
        "delta": "0:00:00.008597", 
        "end": "2018-10-27 13:37:00.123456", 
        "rc": 0, 
        "end": "2018-10-27 13:37:01.123456", 
        "stderr": "", 
        "stderr_lines": [], 
        "stdout": "pinapplepie.my.lan.domain", 
        "stdout_lines": [
            "pinapplepie.my.lan.domain", 
        ]
    }
}
```

1. How do I run my tasks serialized?
2. What "with_" loop should I be using?

Thanks for your time.
Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate like this (note that fruit is not a dictionary, its a list of dictionaries):

```
---
- name: test
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    fruit:
       - name: banana
         color: yellow

       - name: apple
         color: green

       - name: tomato
         color: red

  tasks:
    - name: Task 1 - Get my hostname
      shell: "hostname -f"
      register: variable

    - name: Task 2 - print my hostname and the fruit
      debug: 
        msg: "hostname.stdout has value {{ variable.stdout }}, the fruits got is: {{ item.name }}"
      with_items: "{{ fruit }}"
```